Build Failed Android Studio Kotlin Jetpack compose
I've been trying to run my app for days with no success
BUILD FAILED in 8m 32s
48 actionable tasks: 2 executed, 46 up-to-date
Configuration cache entry reused

Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':androidApp:compileDebugKotlin'.

Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\LENOVO\AndroidStudioProjects\Mi2u\androidApp\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\example\sample_project\android\chatsui\ChatsExpandKt$ChatsExpand$lambda$140$lambda$139$lambda$138$$inlined$items$default$4.class (The system cannot find the file specified)
Execution failed for task ':androidApp:compileDebugKotlin'.

A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction


Have you tried a clean/rebuild and invalidated caches?

I invalidated caches but still no progress

Step one buy new computer build failed 8minutes(!) Step two try to download a newer version of Android studio, and make all the updates etc...

@tyg I'm updating the question to show you the code that's bringing the errors
